# What happened to the sample Portland gp services?

Tags: arcgis-server, rest

I'm trying to use a sample asynch gpservice.

The Portland services ( http://sampleserver2.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Portland )
returns 500.

It is used as a reference implementation in the online doc:
http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/rest/index.html?gpexecute.html

Does anyone know of an asynchronous gp service I can test against?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the whole Portland folder is gone from sampleserver2, and I didn't see any on ss1 or 3 either.

Here are a couple async gp services used in the Silverlight API samples

[Clip Counties GPServer](http://serverapps.esri.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/SamplesNET/USA_Data_ClipTools/GPServer/ClipCounties) - used in [this sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#ClipFeatures)

[Buffer Points](http://serverapps.esri.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/SamplesNET/BufferTools/GPServer/BufferPoints) - not sure if there is a live demo

Answer (score 2):

I just remembered the great thing about REST services is they get indexed by google, which means I can find lots of asynch services by [googling for "Execution Type: esriExecutionTypeAsynchronous"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22Execution+Type%3a+esriExecutionTypeAsynchronous%22) (with quotes).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the service was decommissioned. I haven't seen anything official but yesterday there was a [post in esri's javascript forum about a service used in an identify sample being "deprecated."](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/13447-Identify-sample-not-working?p=40988&viewfull=1#post40988) Might be worth posting over there to see if you can get clarification from an esri employee.

Answer (score 1):

The Portland Services were indeed decommissioned on September 20th. I believe there wasn't an official announcement probably because it's a sample services and not production. As an alternative for testing purposes I'd also suggest trying out the Homeland Security asynchronous geoprocessing task: http://sampleserver4.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/HomelandSecurity/Incident_Data_Extraction/GPServer